# push_back issue std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

OSX 10.7, XCode 4.

I have a small problem: I need to push back a 2D `vector<vector<float>>` in to a 3D Vector, after a process of selection. It throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the push_back function in the stl::vector template. It seems like it should be simple (I've worked with complex data structures many times before), I've tried a varying amount of ideas but to no avail. Everything else works and outputs the values that I'd expect to the command line. I'm sure its code blindness, and some easy rep to pick up.

I ask only because I believe that my syntax is correct, but at compile time I have issues. Heres some sample code:

Implementation:

```
for(int i=0;i<fdisVec.size();i++){

    int j;

        if(fdisVec[i] < fdisVec2[i]){

            j = 0;

        }

        else if(fdisVec2[i] < fdisVec[i]){

            j = 1;

        }

    clusters[j].push_back(allMfccs[i]);

}
```

and my .h has the objects declared as such (public members of class):

```
    vector< vector <float> > allMfccs;
    vector< vector < vector <float> > > clusters;
```

In case it helps, fdisVec and fdisVec2 are also 2d Vectors, however, the "if else" statement responds how I want it to - I highly doubt it would be something to do with that.

Comment: If you are dealing with vecs of vecs of floats you might want to consider using a matrix type like boost::numeric::ublas::matrix. It has a STL like interface. Try using .at() instead of [] and see if you get an exception thrown.

Comment: What are the sizes?  Could you be running out of memory?

Comment: If the values are equal `j` is unintialised.

Comment: note: if `fdisVec2[i]` and `fdisVec[i]` are equal, `j` will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if fdisVec[i] == fdisVec2[i] ?

In this case, j is left uninitialized (garbage), and sometimes the value is not a valid index for your clusters vector.

Comment: Just tried changing the if to just a if(fdis < fdis2){j=0} else {j=1} and I'm still getting the same error. That should make it absolutely 1 or 0 all of the time. I don't believe that I'd be going over my memory - its only 2999 indexes in allMfccs all with 2 floats per index.

Comment: What is the value of clusters.size()? allMfccs.size()? fdisVec.size()?

Comment: allMfccs.size() = 2998, fdisVec.size() = 2998, clusters.size() = 0. I haven't used clusters yet, this loop deals with the process of populating that 3D Vector correctly.

Comment: clusters.size()==0 is the problem.  You need to add two empty vectors to it so there is a place to put your values.

Comment: al a cluster[0].push_back(vector<vector<float>>>)?

Comment: clusters.resize(2) should be fine.

Comment: Brilliant, I knew it was something that simple. I was sure it was to do with the allocation of clusters - tried pushing empty vectors on to it and found the same problem, which led me to believe that it was else where. It works now, I will remember the resize() if I hit this fix in the future. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

In spite of the fact that `cluster.size() == 0` will be a problem (as discussed in answer by @VaughnCato) accessing an element of cluster will not lead to a compile-time error, but most likely crash your program when you run it.

However, the compile-time error is due to the fact that `clusters[j]` expects a `vector< vector< float > >` but `allMfccs[i]` is only a `vector< float >`.

So according to your declaration of `clusters` and `allMfccs`, you would need to push `allMfccs`.